# Different color when exporting png in Sketch 2

Tags: color, export, png, sketch-app

I have a problem when I'm exporting a `.png` file in Sketch 2. I have an icon with the background color of `#8FBE00` but when I'm exporting it as a `.png` file the background color is `#8EC003`. I have absolutely no idea what's going on, I've never encountered this problem when working with Sketch before. I'm no Sketch expert so maybe someone can help me.

Comment: Run "pngcheck -v" on your exported .png file to see if it has any color management chunks such as gAMA, iCCP, or sRGB.  Depending on what application you use to observe the background color, these chunks might cause slight color differences.

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson how do I run "pngcheck -v" on my file?

Comment: I noticed that the colors are different when checking them on different screens, but why is the color changed when exporting. As you may notice Im new to this stuff. And I also noticed that all my exported images from Sketch changes color..

Comment: "pngcheck -v file.png".  If you don't have pngcheck installed on your system, you can download it from http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/apps/pngcheck.html

Comment: How do I install it after download @GlennRanders-Pehrson

Comment: How to install things depends on your platform.  If you are on Windows, download the Win32 .zip file, unzip it, and run pngcheck.exe -v file.png.  If not we will probably have to take this to a chat.  Maybe you already have pngcrush; you could do 'pngcrush -n -v file.png' to get a chunk list.  There are many other applications that will also list the PNG chunks including TweakPNG and SNG.

Comment: @Oskar PNGs saved from Sketch can have an sRGB or gAMA chunk, but do not have an ICC profile chunk:  https://bjango.com/articles/pngoptimisation/ I do not think that’s the issue.

Comment: The current version of Sketch does not have this problem. Maybe time to upgrade? It’s very likely setting tour display to sRGB in System Preferences would solve the issue, but I wouldn't recommend that.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a quick test with 2 exports from Sketch, with and without Color profile.

[image: With Color Profile]

When I use the **Mac DigitalColor Meter** it measures exactly the same colors.

If I use **Affinity Photo** it's the same. It assigns a color profile to the png file that does not have it and measures the exact hexadecimal values.

Processing the images with a PNG compressor removing EXIF meta and color profile data does not change any values measured.

### So

- Sketch always save as sRGB (not gAMA) with the 'Save for web' unchecked.
- If 'Save for web' is checked, opening that image in any software will append a color profile. Luckily would be sRGB and it will have the same created colour in Sketch.
- Opening the png image in Safari will be interpreted as sRGB.

Answer (score -2):

The problem may be that when you are working in Photoshop your file is being color managed. You can turn that off and it should allow you to maintain the color you want. I‘ve included a link that explains how to turn off color management in photoshop. http://bjango.com/articles/photoshop/ I found it through a link on hack design.

Comment: THat article is so wrong. You really never want to turn "off" color management. It goes to show how 1 person with the wrong information who likes to write can spread mis-information. http://digitaldog.net has better information.  In addition, the question specifically asks about Sketch, not Photoshop.

Comment: I assumed you were creating the png file from a photoshop document. My bad. I’ll have to check out digitaldog.net

Comment: Late to the party ... Pretty sure @marc-edwards (active here) is behind Bjango. Would be nice if he'd chime in.

Comment: @Scott The article is not wrong, if you’re doing screen design and using an sRGB like display. It is important to recognise that appearance isn’t the only concern when it comes to colour management (values matching, rounding issues and avoiding clipping can take priority).

Comment: Yeah @MarcEdwards we've had this conversation. Your misguided advice to disable color management is horrible in my opinion.

Comment: @Scott It’s not something you’ll understand unless you do UI design. Print design principles can’t be applied. UI design typically runs on fixed sRGB platforms. Rounding, clipping and an effective pipeline are far more important. You just can’t take the same approach as print work. Display P3 changes some things and I need to update that article, but if you’re not making apps, you can’t assume you understand what’s needed. Either way, it’s not the issue in the case.

Comment: I disagree Mark. And assuming I have no experience with design for screen rendering at all is, well, rather arrogant.